# In laravel Route::get('user/{id}', where does "id" come from?

Tags: laravel

I am an old sea-dog learning new tricks.

Given this route:
`Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@showProfile');`
where does the value of "id" come from? It is the variable $id in:

```
public function show($id)
{   $post=\DB::table('events')->where('id',$id)->first();
    return view('post',['post'=>$post]);
}
```

Comment: laravel by default when you add a wildcard variable in your route it binds to your action (method) in your controller

Comment: `Route::get('user/{id}'...` means, your URI will be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/1` if your `id` is 1

Comment: for more information, you can read the laravel lifecycle document.

Comment: OK, this old sea-dog is not as sharp as he used to be.  Where does the "1" in http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/1 come from?

Comment: That is request which client sends to server (i.e. browser, postman, mobile app). It is arbitrary value. To be precise it is request url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to give explanation that can be understood by even a old sea-dog, we need to go from php.
Lets take a simple example, we have two files `user.php` and `profile.php`
In `user.php`, we have a simple link to profile.php

```
<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"style="text-decoration: none"><?php echo $nume;?></a>><?php echo $id;?></a>
```

Then we can access the id and uri in `profile.php` using `$_GET` and `$_SERVER`

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id . "<br>" . $uri;
```

To implement similar concept in object-oriented representation of the HTTP request, we use Request class which allow to interact with the HTTP request  in an easier way.(For more details, you can see Documentation on [Http fundamentals by Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html))

The concept of using http request in ordered and better way of object orientation was first provided by (at least as per my knowledge) by symfony, in the
 `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` class. You can retrieve the same output as $_GET from php using one of its method

```
$request->query->get('id'); // retrieves $_GET and $_POST variables respectively
```

You can see [Symfony Request Object](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object) for more methods.

---

### **how parameters( even wildcards ) are taken in Laravel**

Now coming to the main portion how these parameters passed in the uri(routes) are accessed by controllers.
For that we need to see the [class Illuminate/Http/Request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php),
As you can see it extends `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as SymfonyRequest` and it inherits all the basic request properties of this class, so you get access to all the properties of `Symfony Request Object` including the methods such as get() which retrieves the parameter from the uri.

---

**Controller**

The controller extends BaseController which is nothing but an abstract class `Illuminate\Routing\Controller` which has a method named [callAction($method, $parameters)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php#L52) which is responsible for executing an action on the controller.
If we go a little deeper, we can see that it is called by the method called [dispatch(Route $route, $controller, $method)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php#L38) in `Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher` class, it is the main method which dispatches a request to the given controller and method.
 As you can see it has an argument named $route from `\Illuminate\Routing\Route`
This Route class has methods such as [matches(Request $request, $includingMethod = true)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L302) which determines if the route matches a given request along with methods such as `hasParameter()` and `hasParameter($name)` which determines if the route has parameter like the one mentioned in your question `'user/{id}'` or the given parameter exists in the route. 
Once determined, the method called [parameter($name, $default = null)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L383) helps to obtain the parameters(this answers your question  Where does the "1" in 127.0.0.1:8000/user/1 come from? ) from the route to the controller and action can be permformed on that.

Comment: If someone find something that can improve or correct the answer please inform me, I believe though the answer is long but if read with the links provided as references with this answer, it does explains the whole journey of how the laravel request passes the parameter from route to the controller.

Comment: bhucho, i like your answer. You have helped an old sea-dog learn a new trick. Thanks...Dan'l