# how does keyword 'use ' works in php (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I don't understand how does use keyword works in laravel framework

I create a controller `PostsManagerController.php`

this controller has a `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

until here everything is fine
the problem is in `routes/web.php`

i find this two lines

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PostsManagerController;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

my question is how  `routes/web.php` know the PostsManagerController class and Route class  without import any of them

as I know if we want use or deal with a class in other file first we need to import it

Comment: There's an autoloader at work somewhere.

Comment: The autoloader specifies where to find a class, the use declaration tells php what namespace that class is in, usually some subset of the autoloading path. Your route definitions should `use` your controllers if you are using a class as a callback.  Without seeing the web.php file, it's hard to say why it's working.

Comment: If you want to know how whenever a route is called from uri, how it goes through routes/web.php to the controller to its assigned method to performaction, you can check this answer I recently wrote https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182852/in-laravel-routegetuser-id-where-does-id-come-from/64188555#64188555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Laravel app there is a `public` folder . there is a file name `index.php`..which require..

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

**Note** `index.php` is the entry point of Laravel application

in `vendor` folder..  if you go there there is a file `autoload.php`

```
// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInita990d9507b876ea05d2300077581f677::getLoader();
```

`autoload.php` file autoload all classes file...